# How to get pid of mpich processes

Tags: linux, mpi, openmpi, mpich

I'm running my execuatable through mpirun command. I want to get the pid of processes being created so that I could kill them later if required. I'm using MPICH. In openmpi there is an option -report-pid which gives pids. Is there anything similar in MPICH?

Comment: You can just look at `top` or let your program print its pid.

Comment: That whole idea of killing the MPI process won't work portably because the process probably runs on a different node. Stopping `mpirun` should stop all processes it spawned ... and there's also `MPI_Abort`.

Comment: You can check the MPIR Process Acquisition Interface. It is used by debuggers to attach MPI jobs. If you are running under a resource manager, you can also have it kill the job for you.